# How to "explain in words" these $3$ conditions at infinity and zero?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions, notation

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^N\setminus \{0\}\to\mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb R$ be functions satisfying
$$a)\qquad f(x)\le \frac{1}{|x|} \text{ when } |x|\sim 0,$$
$$b)\qquad \nabla f(x)\to 0\quad\text{ as } |x|\to +\infty,$$
$$c)\quad|g(x)|+\sum_{i=1}^N \left\vert\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} g(x)\right\vert\to 1\quad\text{ as } |x|\to +\infty. $$

I am trying to "traduce in words" these three conditions. As on the one hand $a)$ can be said as $f$ grows less that $1/|x|$ for $x$ small and $b)$ as the gradient of $f$ is infinitesimal at infinity respectively, I have no idea how to explain condition $c)$.

Could someone please help me with that? Also, there is a better way to explain conditions $a)$ and $b)$, too?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: on C I suspect that's supposed to be $x_i$ as the partial and not $x_1$?

Comment: @Alan you are right. Question edited.

Comment: maybe "g and its gradient are bounded, and they are not very small simultanuously" , for large $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) The function $f$ of $x$ should be bounded from above (or dominated) by the function $1$ over the norm of $x$ when $x$ is sufficiently close to $0$.

b) The gradient of $f$ should tend (or converge, or trend, or go) to $0$ as $x$ goes (or tends, or converges, or trends) to infinity.

c) (If I have understood it correctly) The absolute value of $g(x)$ plus the $\ell^1$ norm of its gradient at $x$ (alternatively you can call this the sum of the magnitudes (or absolute values) of the components of the gradient of $g$) must go to $0$ as $x$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Hi! Edited a presumed typo. Feel free to revert if I did so in error!